# Perform Method With int Return Value in Background Thread

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading

I'm trying to speed up my application performance by performing calculations in background threads but I'm having trouble doing this. Originally I had been using

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(calculateValue:) withObject:[words objectAtIndex:row]];
```

which was fine when my selector was a void method. However, I'm trying to do something similar to but obviously the below code isn't valid.

```
int value = [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(calculateValue:) withObject:[words objectAtIndex:row]];
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Updated**

Here is the route I'm currently going. I don't know how to call back to the main thread to send the updated value from computeWordValue to my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    int value = [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(calculateWordValue:) withObject:[wordsSection objectAtIndex:row]];
    NSString *pointValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Point:%d",value];
    cell.pointLabel.text = pointValue;
 }

-(void)calculateWordValue:(NSString *)word {

  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(computeWordValue:) withObject:word waitUntilDone:YES];
}

-(int)computeWordValue:(NSString *)word {

  return totalValue; //This will be a randomly generated number
}
```

Comment: How fast / slow is the `calculateWordValue` and why are you trying to run it in the background at that point?

Comment: It performs a lot of calculations, I just simplified it for posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres a way I use to do it:

```
 -(void) calculateValue:(id) obj
  {
       // calculate value
       [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(didFinishCalculating:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:value]];
  }

 -(void) didFinishCalculating:(NSNumber *) val
 {
       // do what you need to do here
 }
```

This really doesn't solve your problem I don't think, but it should at least give you a starting point.

UPDATE:

Your new code shows me that you don't really need to perform this in the background, just cache the value using an NSDictionary or something. Here's an example:

```
 -(int) calculateValue:(id) obj
 {
        if ([valuesCache objectForKey:obj] == nil)
        {
            // calculate value
            [valuesCache setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:result] forKey:obj];
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return [[valuesCache objectForKey:obj] intValue];
        }
 }
```

Comment: I think it solves the problem perfectly well.  The issue is, of course, that you have to deliver the result on the main thread asynchronously and the easiest way to do this is to use `performSelectorOnMainThread:`

Comment: I followed those suggestions but I'm still a bit confused on how to pass the int value back. I've added more code above for more context.

Comment: This doesn't adress the actual question of returning the value to the main thread. @Joe: See ogotts answer.

Comment: When you use a delegate, it doesn't automatically call on the main thread, you have to explicitly run it on the main thread by `[myDelegate performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:]`

Answer (score 1):

There's no way `-performSelectorInBackground: ...` could return the value of the method you're calling because it actually returns before the selector was even executed. That selector will be executed on a background thread asap.

The solution is handling the result of your method asynchronously, as Richard pointed out (the method in his answer should be `- (void)didFinishCalculating:(NSNumber*)val`, because only objects can be passed in `-performSelector: ...` calls):

- Perform your selector on a background thread
- Call your result handler method on the main thread. You should do that on the main thread in just about any case because some things in Mac OS X and iOS are designed to just run on the main thread, like GUI updates.